# Android's View disappears immediately when trying to animate it off the screen

Tags: android, view, transition

Well, I have some View's hierarchy with

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

in every View from top to bottom of the tree.

Also, I have a LinearLayout with

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

, and every time I change the layout somehow - the transition runs smoothly like I want it to.

But.

SOME internal views (not all of them, only some) dissappearing immediately, like I turn their visibility to GONE, when I tryng to bring them off the screen smoothly.

I checked thousands of times: ALL the hierarchy has

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

So how can it be like this?

Comment: late reply,but yre you using FULL_SCREEN window feature?

Comment: I'm having the same problema, how did you solve it?